# GIMP tools have stopped working

Tags: 12.04, gimp, ubuntu-studio

GIMP has stopped working.

My GIMP program tools (selection tools other than the menu select all, paint bucket, pencil, paint brush, eraser, spraybrush etc.) stopped working.

I have Ubuntu Studio 12_04 LTS and all the programs are completely up to date.

GIMP version 2.6.12-1ubuntu1.3 upgraded 7/22/2014

Comment: What exactly is "stopped working" in your case?

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the old profile

```
mv ~/.gimp-2.6/  ~/.gimp-2.6.bak
```

I restarted GIMP and it worked!